# Content in reactstrap modal continues to exist after closing using enzyme/jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, reactstrap

I'm trying to do some testing with enzyme and jest in react, and things work fine when I open a modal e.g. input fields in the modal aren't there and the modal state is false (as intended) when I try to find them using

`expect(wrapper.find("input")).toHaveLength(0);`

and do exist after I've opened the modal using

```
const edit = wrapper.find("Button.update-button");
edit.simulate("click");
expect(wrapper.find("input")).toHaveLength(2);
```

which all works (including the modal state turning to true after it opens) as intended. But when I close the modal, the state gets toggled off correctly, but the modal content (e.g. the input boxes and buttons in the modal) still exist when I try:

```
expect(wrapper.find("input")).toHaveLength(0);
```

I still somehow have 2 input fields that shouldn't be there as the modal is closed.

Here is my code for the component I am trying to test if that helps:

```
/*
    Artefact Component displays just UI for the Artefact itself and it's information.
*/

import React, { Component } from "react";

import DeleteArtefact from "../DeleteArtefact";
import UpdateArtefact from "../UpdateArtefact";

import {
    Card,
    CardImg,
    CardTitle,
    CardBody,
    ButtonGroup,
    Button,
    CardFooter
} from "reactstrap";

class Artefact extends Component {
    // Initialise State
    state = {
        updatemodal: false,
        deletemodal: false
    };

    // Toggle function for toggling modal open/close
    toggleUpdate = () => {
        this.setState({
            updatemodal: !this.state.updatemodal
        });
    };

    toggleDelete = () => {
        this.setState({
            deletemodal: !this.state.deletemodal
        });
    };

    prepareUpdateState = () => {
        this.props.editUpdate(this.props.artefact);
        this.toggleUpdate();
    };

    render() {
        const {
            artefact,
            onChange,
            onUpdateClick,
            editUpdate,
            onDeleteClick
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardImg
                    src={artefact.img}
                    alt={`Image for Artefact ${artefact.name}`}
                />
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>
                        <h6>{artefact.name}</h6>
                    </CardTitle>
                </CardBody>
                <CardFooter>
                    <ButtonGroup>
                        <Button
                            className="update-button"
                            color="dark"
                            onClick={this.prepareUpdateState}
                        >
                            Edit
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            className="delete-button"
                            color="dark"
                            onClick={this.toggleDelete}
                        >
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                    </ButtonGroup>
                    <UpdateArtefact
                        artefact={artefact}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        onUpdateClick={onUpdateClick}
                        editUpdate={editUpdate}
                        toggle={this.toggleUpdate}
                        modal={this.state.updatemodal}
                    />
                    <DeleteArtefact
                        _id={artefact._id}
                        onDeleteClick={onDeleteClick}
                        toggle={this.toggleDelete}
                        modal={this.state.deletemodal}
                    />
                </CardFooter>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default Artefact;
```

And here is the UpdateArtefact Component that has the modal I'm trying to test:

```
/*
    UpdateArtefact Component is a child Component of ArtefactGallery and
    creates a new Artefact by using functions onChange() and updateClick() 
    and editUpdate() which are passed as props from ArtefactGallery and 
    passes state back up and makes api calls using axios.
*/

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Button,
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input
} from "reactstrap";

class UpdateArtefact extends Component {
    // Passes state up to ArtefactGallery component and updates the artefact.
    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onUpdateClick(this.props.artefact._id);
        this.props.toggle();
    };

    // Sets state in ArtefactGallery to the initial values of the artefact
    // to prepare for any edits to be made in the case that some fields have
    // no change, so that there are no null fields.
    prepareUpdateState = () => {
        this.props.editUpdate(this.props.artefact);
        this.props.toggle();
    };

    render() {
        const { artefact } = this.props;
        return (
            <div style={{ marginLeft: "1rem" }}>
                <Modal isOpen={this.props.modal} toggle={this.props.toggle}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggle}>
                        Edit Artefact
                    </ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label>Artefact</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="name"
                                    id="artefactName"
                                    defaultValue={artefact.name}
                                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                                />
                                <Label>Image</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="img"
                                    id="artefactImg"
                                    defaultValue={artefact.img}
                                    onChange={this.props.onChange}
                                />
                                <Button
                                    className="modal-submit-button"
                                    color="dark"
                                    style={{ marginTop: "2rem" }}
                                    block
                                >
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </FormGroup>
                        </Form>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default UpdateArtefact;
```

So basically I just want to know what the reason if for why the modal content is still being picked up by enzyme and how to fix this. I've tried searching all over but couldn't find an answer so I'm guessing there's something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, your components does not use conditional rendering like

```
{someFlag && <SomeElement>}
```

but just pass down `isOpen` prop:

```
<Modal isOpen={this.props.modal} toggle={this.props.toggle}>
```

so probably `Modal` just hides its `props.children` and `input` is kept.

As a workaround you may validate against `ModalComponentYouHaveRendered.props().isOpen` instead of checking amount of `input`s

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just tried doing {this.props.modal && <Component>} (so basically adding the flag to do conditional rendering) and my tests work now! Just wondering though, why does what I did not work? Why would the modal just hide the props.children when the modal is meant to open/close based on the state?

Comment: Also when I add conditional rendering for some reason I get this error: Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead. 
when I try the ModalComponentYouHaveRendered.props().isOpen aswell, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: you either use conditional rendering and in some cases there will be no `Modal` exists. Or avoiding conditional rendering and checking `props().isOpen`. Trying to combine both you are getting case where popup legitimately absent but you're trying to access its props.

Comment: Ooooh ok thank you! Are there benefits to one that outweigh the other which would result in using one over the other? or is it purely down to preference then?

Comment: approaches provide difference in behavior(say, if some data loading in `componentDidMount`is run when popup is not open yet), cannot say one way is better than another. just try keeping single way across your codebase

Comment: So for example if I don't conditional rendering then data loading could run and load up before the modal opens so I wouldn't need to wait for it to load after i open it? whereas if I did do conditional rendering it would only need to load if I actually opened it? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: to be precise, even for `isOpen` approach component may skip loading on mount if it is not displayed yet, but it's up to component. and one more thing: it's really confusing to use conditional rendering on existing component that has this `isOpen` prop(like `{someFlag && <Popup isOpen={true }`) better avoid such composition

Comment: ooh ok thanks, so if I use conditional rendering I should remove the isOpen prop then?

Comment: if it is just training app or you're sure in your unit tests, then yes, it can be removed in favor of conditional rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

`wrapper.update()`

after closing the modal.

In this way, the wrapper should get updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i still get an error when I use that after closing the modal as enzyme still finds 2 input fields after the modal is closed (even the the state gets updated)